# Custom Toolbar in UINavigation Controller

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am having trouble understanding what approach to take to customize my own Toolbar in Xamarin.ios. The Navigation controller comes with its own default toolbar but how can i change the height and have my own buttons, background image.

What is the best approach for the above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom navigationBar as you want .

```
public class xxxViewController: UIViewController
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);



            NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;


            double height = IsiphoneX();

            UIView backView = new UIView()
            {
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
                Frame = new CGRect(0,20,UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, height),

            };


            UIButton backBtn = new UIButton() {

                Frame = new CGRect(20, height-44, 40, 44),
                Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18),

            } ;
            backBtn.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
            backBtn.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Blue, UIControlState.Normal);
            backBtn.AddTarget(this,new Selector("GoBack"),UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);

            UILabel titleLabel = new UILabel() {
                Frame=new CGRect(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width/2-75, 0,150, height),
                Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20),
                Text = "xxx",
                TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                Lines = 0,

            };

            UILabel line = new UILabel() {

                Frame = new CGRect(0, height, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 0.5),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black,

            };

            backView.AddSubview(backBtn);
            backView.AddSubview(titleLabel);
            backView.AddSubview(line);

            View.AddSubview(backView);
        }


         double IsiphoneX()
        {

            double height = 44;

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().SafeAreaInsets.Bottom > 0.0)
                {
                    height = 64;
                }
            }

            return height;
        }

        [Export("GoBack")]
        void GoBack()
        {
            NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

            NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = false;
        }

    }
```

You can set the property of title , backButton and navigationBar as you need (such as text , color ,BackgroundColor ,font e.g.)