# Need to set line height of navigation title for custom font in IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms.entry

Im just set custom font on all text area but fonts creating little longer than space on place. Upper side of text cutting. I fixed it on label items with set lineheight to 1.2. But i cant doin it on my navigation title and entry boxes.

This is my navigation custom renderer:

```
   public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Clear;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = true;

        UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName("CooperHewitt-Bold", 20),
            TextColor = UIColor.White
        });
    }
```

I need to set line height on entry too.

Comment: No, i just skipped but your solution works. However its getting my work harder because of new page renderer etc. Thanks for help.

Comment: Here is a similar issue that you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845226/custom-toolbar-in-uinavigation-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my issue with make a new view and set it as TitleView.

```
 <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                   //.... 
 x:Class="MyApp.Views.CustomNavTitle">
    <StackLayout x:Name="stack" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,25,0">
        <Label Style="{StaticResource NavigationBarTitle}" Text="{Binding .}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

And set it if it was IOS device on my content pages constructor.

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, new CustomNavTitle() { BindingContext = Title });
```

And I setted "LineHeight" (as 1.2) prop and set custom font family which i want to the label in NavigationBarTitle style.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Navigation Bar and set the style of it as you want.

> in Customrenderer

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
  base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

  NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;


  double height = IsiphoneX();

  UIView backView = new UIView()
  {
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
    Frame = new CGRect(0,20,UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, height),
  };


  UIButton backBtn = new UIButton() {

     Frame = new CGRect(20, height-44, 40, 44),
     Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18),

  } ;

  backBtn.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
  backBtn.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Blue, UIControlState.Normal);
  backBtn.AddTarget(this,new Selector("GoBack"),UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);

  UILabel titleLabel = new UILabel() 
     {
      Frame=new CGRect(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width/2-75, 0,150, height),
      Font = UIFont.FromName("CooperHewitt-Bold", 20),
      Text = "xxx",
      TextColor = UIColor.Black,
      Lines = 0,
     };

     UILabel line = new UILabel() {

         Frame = new CGRect(0, height, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 0.5),
         BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black,

     };

     backView.AddSubview(backBtn);
     backView.AddSubview(titleLabel);
     backView.AddSubview(line);

     View.AddSubview(backView);
}


double IsiphoneX()
{

  double height = 44;

  if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
   {
     if(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().SafeAreaInsets.Bottom > 0.0)
       {
          height = 64;
       }
   }

   return height;
}

[Export("GoBack")]
void GoBack()
{
  NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
  base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

  NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = false;
}
```

You can set the property of title , backButton and navigationBar as you need (such as text , color ,BackgroundColor ,font e.g.)

> For entry , you can also set height in CustomRenderer

```
using UIKit;
using xxx.iOS;


using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using CoreGraphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEnterRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public  class MyEnterRenderer:EntryRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(new CustomTextField());
            }

        }

    }

    public class CustomTextField:UITextField
    {


        public CustomTextField()
        {
            Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20,2);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: But i just wanted to set line height of title with using native navigation bar. Not create new one. İts broke my navigations and tabbed pages.

Comment: What means of broke your  navigations and tabbed pages ? It have the same function with native navigation bar .

Comment: I mean when i use custom nav bar my page contents are disappear.

Comment: You should create a customrenderer of PageRenderer .